# Python negative timedelta issue

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with negative values for my definition. Whenever ft is negative it will return an error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

```
def formatTime(_seconds):
    ft = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=_seconds))
    if int(ft[0]) <= 0:
        ms = ft.find('.')
        if ms < 0:
            return "%s.000" % ft[2:11]
        else:
            return ft[2:11]
    else:
        x = ft.find(':')
        if x > -1:
            hlen = len(ft[0:x])
            ms = ft.find('.')
            if ms < 0:
                return "%s.000" % ft[0:((11 + hlen) -1)]
            else:
                return ft[0:((11 + hlen) -1)]
        else:
            x = ft.find('.')
            if x > -1:
                ms = ft.find('.')
                if ms < 0:
                    return "%s.000" % ft[0:(x + 4)]
                else:
                    return ft[0:(x + 4)]
            else:
                ms = ft.find('.')
                if ms < 0:
                    return "%s.000" % ft[0:11]
                else:
                    return ft[0:11]
```

I'm a beginner and I'm honestly lost now.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Whenever ft is negative it will return an error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

I'm trying to get the actual negative value print out. Positive values are working fine.

Comment: I already saw that, I am asking what are you trying to do with this code. Provide some sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: It's a definition of time formatting. I'm using this definition to format my time counter. The timer counts down and once it reaches 0 I'm getting the error described above. I'd like it to keep counting below 0 and get a negative number print out.

Comment: what is all that code supposed to do in the first place? what are the used input parameters, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

One problem is here:

```
ft = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=_seconds))
print(ft) # I added this
if int(ft[0]) <= 0:
```

Output:

```
>>> formatTime(-10)
-1 day, 23:59:50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 5, in formatTime
    if int(ft[0]) <= 0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

As you can see, `ft[0]` is the single character `'-'`, which can't be converted to an integer.

Consider using `ft = datetime.timedelta(seconds=_seconds).total_seconds()`, which returns a signed float, for your calculation.

Comment: What would be the workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting it to string you can do something like this:

```
>>> def convert_timedelta(duration):
        #http://goo.gl/Ci4wP
        days, seconds = duration.days, duration.seconds
        hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
        minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
        seconds = (seconds % 60)
        return hours, minutes, seconds,duration.microseconds
... 
>>> d = timedelta(seconds = -.50)
>>> h, m, sec, ms = convert_timedelta(d)
>>> h
-1
>>> m
59
>>> sec
59
>>> ms
500000
```

Now you can use these variables `h`,`m`, `sec` and `ms` to do your stuff.